# Deleting A File From Another Unrelated Work Station Through The Internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-management

I have a handfull of client computers unrelated and very far from my main workstation, and I have their `IP`s and physical addresses.

The problem here is that I have to constantly delete some files (shared files) on the clients' computers  for business purposes but it has to be me, so I need to do it manually from distance.

How can I do this? For the record I'm using `Windows 7` on all the machines and would love if there is a way to do this without installing an outside program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this unfortunately with just an ip or physical address. You would need to either use a vpn or software like teamviewer.

Comment: Alright I'm more and more beginning to accept the fact, is teamviewer the best way to do it via an outside software?

Comment: Yes I'd say it's probably the easiest way. A harder but better way would be to set up and FTP server